# Kotlin - How to call nullable method with receiver only if it exists?

Tags: function, kotlin, lambda, nullable, receiver

I have a function that accepts an `Article` and nullable method with `Article` as its receiver. I want to call the nullable method and return its results only if it exists. How can I do this?

```
fun foo(article: Article, method: (Article.() -> String)? = null): String? =
    article?.method() // how can I do this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun foo(article: Article, method: (Article.() -> String)? = null): String? =
    method?.invoke(article)
```

or

```
fun foo(article: Article, method: (Article.() -> String)? = null): String? =
    method?.let { article.it() }
```